# Apply function not working in R on data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame:
    `rawDataLogged`

I have a function:

```
doForRow <- function(row) {
  transpose <- t(row);
  transpose <- transpose[like(row.names(transpose), "H.M")]
  frame <- data.frame(transpose)
  frame$BR <- c(1,1,2,2)
  frame$TR <- c(1,2,1,2)
  colnames(frame)[1] <- "Log2Ratio"
  frame$Log2Ratio <- as.numeric(levels(frame$Log2Ratio))[frame$Log2Ratio]
  summ <- summary(aov(Log2Ratio ~ BR + Error(TR), data=frame))
  summ[[2]][[1]]["BR",]$'Pr(>F)'  
}
```

If I execute my function with a row from my data frame, I get a result:
`> doForRow(rawDataLogged[5,])
[1] 0.4973168`

However if I try to use 'apply' to get the results for all my rows, it does not work:

```
tmp <- apply(rawDataLogged, 1, doForRow)

 Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "BR", value = c(1, 1, 2, 2)) : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 0
```

When I place a breakpoint in my own function, I see that 'row' is empty, as in nothing seems to be getting passed into my function by apply.

Any ideas why this could be happening? I've spent hours trying to solve this myself, perhaps a loop would be easiest instead of an apply family function. I'm at a loss as to why my function is called without any row data.

I have placed an R data file containing the 'rawDataLogged' object at this url: [Link](http://pgb.liv.ac.uk/files/exampleData) which could be used for debugging. Example data created using dput: [Link](http://pgb.liv.ac.uk/files/exampleData_dput_small)

Here is a dump from `str` to show the structure of my data frame:

```
'data.frame':   1262 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Protein.IDs              : Factor w/ 1262 levels "sp|A0AVT1|UBA6_HUMAN;tr|H0Y8S8|H0Y8S8_HUMAN",..: 654 190 894 196 834 268 474 1221 366 973 ...
 $ Majority.protein.IDs     : Factor w/ 1262 levels "sp|A0AVT1|UBA6_HUMAN",..: 654 190 894 196 834 268 474 1221 366 973 ...
 $ Ratio.M.L.normalized.X1.1: num  -0.27 -0.707 0.244 -0.728 -2.025 ...
 $ Ratio.H.L.normalized.X1.1: num  0.0036 0.0588 -0.0886 0.1561 -0.0843 ...
 $ Ratio.H.M.normalized.X1.1: num  0.339 0.66 -0.211 0.477 1.926 ...
 $ Ratio.M.L.normalized.X1.2: num  -0.132 -0.661 0.283 -1.045 -1.223 ...
 $ Ratio.H.L.normalized.X1.2: num  -0.07779 0.10273 -0.00251 -0.09755 0.18929 ...
 $ Ratio.H.M.normalized.X1.2: num  0.0793 0.7718 -0.2657 0.9651 1.3532 ...
 $ Ratio.M.L.normalized.X3.1: num  -3.55 -2.08 -1.99 -1.98 -1.85 ...
 $ Ratio.H.L.normalized.X3.1: num  0.1336 0.0777 -0.1014 -0.3478 -0.0259 ...
 $ Ratio.H.M.normalized.X3.1: num  -0.187 2.259 1.852 1.511 1.928 ...
 $ Ratio.M.L.normalized.X3.2: num  0.106 -2.118 -1.864 -2.364 -1.847 ...
 $ Ratio.H.L.normalized.X3.2: num  0.0141 0.0746 -0.0315 -0.1772 -0.0936 ...
 $ Ratio.H.M.normalized.X3.2: num  -0.143 2.248 1.842 2.279 1.758 ...
 $ id                       : int  1369 564 2170 577 1966 700 1050 1357 855 2482 ...
```

Comment: can't open the file, use `dput()` of a few rows instead

Comment: Also, where does the function `like` come from? It does not appear to be in `base`.

Comment: @coffeinjunky `like` is from the `data.table` package.

Comment: @Jimbou I have added a small number of rows from dput to post. Thanks :)